# Wrong probability calculation in context-free grammar (NLTK, Python 3)

Tags: python, nltk, probability, context-free-grammar, text-parsing

I have a problem with showing the most likely constituency structure of some sentence using NLTK's probabilistic grammar.

Here is my sentence "Ich sah den Tiger under der Felse"

Here is my code:

```
from nltk import PCFG
tiger_grammar = PCFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP [1.0]
NP -> ART NN [0.25] | PPER [0.5] | NP PP [0.25]
VP -> VVFIN NP [0.75] | VVFIN NP PP [0.25]
PP -> APPR NP [1.0]
APPR -> 'unter' [1.0]
PPER -> 'Ich' [1.0]
VVFIN -> 'sah' [1.0]
NN -> 'Tiger' [0.5] | 'Felse' [0.5]
ART -> 'den' [0.5] | 'der' [0.5]
""")
viterbi_parser = nltk.ViterbiParser(tiger_grammar)
trees = viterbi_parser.parse(['Ich', 'sah', 'den', 'Tiger', 'unter', 'der', 'Felse'])
for t in trees:
    print(t)
```

Here is what I get:

```
(S
  (NP (PPER Ich))
  (VP
    (VVFIN sah)
    (NP (ART den) (NN Tiger))
    (PP (APPR unter) (NP (ART der) (NN Felse))))) (p=0.000488281)
```

But the desired result is:

```
(S
  (NP (PPER Ich))
  (VP
    (VVFIN sah)
    (NP
      (NP (ART den) (NN Tiger))
      (PP (APPR unter) (NP (ART der) (NN Felse))))))
```

(I didn't add the probability here, but it should be displayed as well)

According to the grammar, the probability to form `VP` from `VVFIN` and `NP` is higher than from `VVFIN`, `NP` and `PP`. But the parser shows the second structure.

What am I doing wrong?

Would be grateful for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because your desired result has lower probability then the result you got. We can compute the probability of your desired result:

```
S -> NP VP       1.0

NP -> PPER       0.5
PPER -> Ich      1.0

VP -> VVFIN NP   0.75
VVFIN -> sah     1.0
NP -> NP PP      0.25

NP -> ART NN     0.25
ART -> den       0.5
NN -> Tiger      0.5

PP -> APPR NP    1.0
APPR -> unter    1.0

NP -> ART NN     0.25
ART -> der       0.5
NN -> Felse      0.5
```

Multiplied together gets probability `0.0003662109375`, which is definitely less than the result you got `0.000488281`.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the line `NP -> ART NN [0.05] | PPER [0.05] | NP PP [0.9]` and got p=0,0000263671875 against p=0,000001953125. Now everything is correct